$B\subseteq X$ is $\mu$-measurable iff it is Carathéodory-measurable
Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu )$ be a measure space. Define $\mu ^*:2^X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ by $\mu^* (A):=\inf \{\mu (E):A\subseteq E\wedge E\in \Sigma \}$ (that is, $\mu^*$ is the outer measure induced by $\mu$). We say that $B\subseteq X$ is

$\mu$-measurable iff there're $A,C\in \Sigma $ such that $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ and $\mu (C\setminus A)=0$.
Carathéodory-measurable iff $\mu ^* (Y)=\mu^* (Y\cap B)+\mu^*(Y\setminus B)$ for all subsets $Y\subseteq X$.

Suppose that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. How can I show that a subset $B\subseteq X$ is $\mu$-measurable iff it is Carathéodory-measurable?

I was able to obtain the result assuming that $\mu$ is finite. In the case where $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, I was only able to prove the implication $\Rightarrow $.
Thank you for your attention!

EDIT:
Some facts I know

$\Sigma(\mu^*)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$
The set of all $\mu$-measurables sets is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$
For all $A\subseteq X$ there is $E\in \Sigma$ such that $A\subseteq E$ and $\mu^*(A)=\mu (E)$.

